# addEventListener pause not working

Tags: android, cordova, addeventlistener, phonegap, onpause

I'm trying to stop playing music when i'm going to the homescreen (using phonegap/cordova/js).
After some researche I found the eventlistener "pause" to check when user is leaving the app but if I use the code it isn't working. a way to make this work?

My code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
    document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
    document.addEventListener("menubutton", onMenuKeyDown, false);
}

function onPause() {
    console.log('paused');
    alert('paused');
}

function onResume() {
    console.log('resumed');
    alert('resumed');
}

function onMenuKeyDown() {
    console.log('onMenuKeyDown');
    alert('onMenuKeyDown');
}
```

like [this](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/388/cordova-pause-and-resume-event-not-firing) link suggested I also added this to config.xml

```
<preference name="KeepRunning" value="true" />
```

Why isn't it working?

Comment: it should work, check it with `console.log();`

Comment: nope, still does nothing